# Finding difference between a date and Today's date in days

Tags: excel

In my dataset I have a date column that looks like this:

```
Date(Column A)
6/3/2018 4:15
6/2/2018 20:32
5/27/2018 8:56
1/31/2018 2:26
```

In another column I've called "Days Difference", I want to calculate the difference in days between the date listed and todays date. I've written the following formula...

```
= DATEDIF(A2,TODAY(),"d")
```

although the output comes out as something funky like "1/13/1905 0:00", not a simple count such as "2" like I want. I've tried changing cell formats, even removed the last 4 characters of the date column getting rid of the time component but haven't gotten anything working properly. Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: But did you change the formatting of the cell into which you entered the `DATEDIF` formula?

Comment: `=today()-a2` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=INT(TODAY()-A2)
```

formatted as Number.

This counts the "days between", so June 3 to say June 6 (today) is `2` days - you may want to append `+1`.